# Inner join without duplicate values from the left table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL Server, and I have 2 tables: `Invoice` and `InvoiceService`.

**Invoice**:

```
InvoiceID      InvoiceDate     InvoicePrice     InvoicePaidAmount  PatientID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               01-01-2016        50                 30              1
2               01-02-2016       100                100              2
```

**InvoiceService**:

```
ID     InvoiceID     ServiceName     ServicePrice
-------------------------------------------------
1          1         Dermato             20
2          1         ophthalmo           30
3          2         General            100
```

My query:

```
select 
    ServiceName, ServicePrice, InvoiceID, InvoicePrice,
    InvoicePaidAmount, PatientID   
from 
    InvoiceService
inner join 
    Invoice on Invoice.InvoiceID = InvoiceService.InvoiceID
```

Result:

```
ServiceName  ServicePrice InvoiceID  InvoicePrice InvoicePaidAmount PatientID 

Dermato      20            1            50            30               1
ophthalmo    30            1            50            30               1
General      100           2            100           100              2
```

I need  to get non duplicate values from the left table  :
when an invoice  has more than 1 service I want that the invoice price and InvoicePaidAmount don't be repeated like this example:

```
ServiceName  ServicePrice InvoiceID  InvoicePrice InvoicePaidAmount PatientID 

Dermato      20            1            50            30               1
ophthalmo    30            1            0             0                1
General      100           2            100           100              2
```

Comment: Don't tag with DB engines you don't use

Comment: use left join with distinct selection. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want one invoice service to "really" match.

```
select s.ServiceName, s.ServicePrice, i.InvoiceID,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then i.InvoicePrice else 0 end) as InvoicePrice,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then i.InvoicePaidAmount else 0 end) as InvoicePaidAmount,
       i.PatientID   
from Invoice i join
     (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.InvoiceID order by s.id) as seqnum
      from InvoiceService s
     ) s
     on i.InvoiceID = s.InvoiceID
```

Comment: Thank you very much you  saved my day .